# gcc Unable to exec gcc.real: No such file or directory

Tags: gcc, c

```
./configure 
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/home/mob/freeglut-2.8.0':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details

other i.e
 gcc --version
Unable to exec gcc.real: No such file or directory

gcc --version
Unable to exec gcc.real: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Can you give an example of a command that *does* produce the error? Just `gcc` by itself, with no arguments?

Comment: ./configure 
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/home/mob/SDL-1.2.15':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
mob@moc:~/SDL-1.2.15$ gcc --version
Unable to exec gcc.real: No such file or directory

Answer (score 2):

Your error was:

```
C compiler cannot create executables
```

This can usually be solved by installing [build-essential [image: Install build-essential]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/build-essential):

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

If the problem still happens after that, please *edit your question* to show the error message and the *complete and exact* output of `./configure`.

Comment: I tried that. and the problem still the same.

Comment: @X_o Please *edit your question* to show the error message and the *complete and exact* output of `./configure`.

Comment: @X_o Please ***edit your question*** to show the error message and the ***complete** and exact* output of `./configure`. (Is that really the complete output of `./configure`? Even if it is, it's very hard to read error messages in comments because most of their formatting, including line breaks, doesn't appear.)

Comment: Okey I fix by myself !!! :D
ln -si /usb/bin/gcc-4.6 /usr/bin/gcc
and that is all kids..!!

Comment: @X_o Great! I recommend posting that as an a separate answer. Also, I recommend *editing your question as I've requested*, as then it will be possible for people with this problem to find the question--and your answer--by searching for the error message.

Answer (score 1):

okay...!! kids I used to had this problem when I tried to used ./configure with any problem

```
./configure 
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/home/mob/freeglut-2.8.0':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
```

See `config.log' for more details

or tried to see what version of gcc I had installed.

```
gcc --version
Unable to exec gcc.real: No such file or directory
```

okay...!!! 
On my case the solution was.

```
ln -si /usb/bin/gcc-4.6 /usr/bin/gcc
```

and after that I can compile any program in my system.